# Displaying a checkbox in a databound DataGridView

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I am unable to correctly populate a DataGridView checkbox column from a boolean column from a database.

First form_load code:

```
Me.DataGridView1.DataSource = Me.bindingSource1
GetData("SELECT myInt, myBool, myString " & _
        "FROM " & myFavTable & " " & _
        "WHERE (myInt > 100) ORDER BY myString")

formatGrid()
```

In GetData I fill myTable with data:

```
Me.dataAdapter.Fill(myTable)
Me.bindingSource1.DataSource = myTable
```

And finally I format grid the before showing.

I format it manually because loading is much faster than with automatic formatting.

```
    With DataGridView1
        .AllowUserToAddRows = False
        .AllowDrop = False
        .AllowUserToOrderColumns = False
        .AllowUserToResizeRows = False
        .SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect
        .MultiSelect = False
        .Dock = DockStyle.Fill
        .EditMode = DataGridViewEditMode.EditProgrammatically

       With .Columns(0)
            .Name = "postN"
            .HeaderText = "Postal"
            .Width = 55
        End With

        With .Columns(1) 'here should be a checkbox
            .Width = 20
        End With

        With .Columns(2)
            .Name = "colCity"
            .HeaderText = "City"
            .Width = 180
        End With
    End With
```

But with this code, in my column that should show checkboxes the string value `0` is displayed when in database is `FALSE`.

How in this situation can I get checkboxes in the middle column instead of text?

I try with .Columns.Add... before and after binding but with no wanted results.
That way I can get `checkboxes`, but in the new column.

Comment: to make a title http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title

Comment: I authorised @spajce's edit to your title. Please see, ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/), where the consensus is "no, they should not"

Comment: I did not make a tags! Just want a help on "DataGridView" like was described. By removing crucial part of title you can't make it better!

Comment: i just want to clarify what we trying to say, try to see your [previous](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/14328359/revisions) post and if notice that you have one tag and your title has a `DataGridView` mentioned so it's important to tag the `DataGridView` than to makes us our title because by our `tags` it will categorized our post. i hope you understand :)

Comment: Of course I understand. How would then look your user's title "Filling a DataGridView in VB.NET"? "Filling a in"?

Comment: @user973238 what you are trying to do should just work. I have a working example going using autogenerated columns displaying data from a SQL server database using a table adapter. Jeremy Thompson's solution may work with a correctly set DataPropertyName but you shouldn't need to do that here (and you might see the same issue) what is the type of the checkbox column in the datatable - in mind it is simply System.Boolean also - what is the type of the column in the database?

Comment: David, here may be a problem that I don't work with MS database but with PostgreSQL through OdbcDataAdapter. Maybe some things are differently interpreted. Everything work's by default with all my tables. Except, instead of checkboxes I have 0/1 (text) while in database is TRUE/FALSE and column IS boolean. I preffer that way too because of loading speed. Any trick how to get checkboxcolumn at runtime formatting based on my descriptions? Thank you for returning back appropriate title! :)

Comment: @user973238 is this still an open issue? There is at least one way (cellvalueformatting) that I would suggest as a possible solution for what you are seeing, but you have marked this as answered so perhaps you have the solution you need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In design-time add the columns to the DataGridView and set the middle column as a CheckBoxColumn.

Then set:

```
With DataGridView1
   .AutoGenerateColumns = False
```

**Edit:**
I see the problem now. You need to set the DataPropertyName to be the same as the column.

When you add columns to the DataGridView, in that dialog set the DataPropertyName to match the DataTable (myTable) column Names. That's the magic behind the mapping.

[image]

Here is the code:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("TextBoxCol");
dt.Columns.Add("CheckBoxCol");
DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
dr[0] = "Hello";
dr[1] = false;
dt.Rows.Add(dr);
dr = dt.NewRow();
dr[0] = "World";
dr[1] = true;
dt.Rows.Add(dr);
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

[image]

Comment: That way I get new columns?? Designtime+Runtime ones together.

Comment: Thats ok if you are seeing twice the number of columns, simply dont add them at RunTime (since you have specified them at design time). Otherwise look at the Form1.Designer.vb code to see how the Design Time Columns are created and re-use that code and create the columns at RunTime.

Comment: I didnt make runtime columns, something is. Binding source or what? I can't remove that if I would like to stay binded.

Comment: Hmm, I don't know. After giving DatapropertyName I get error "0" is not correct for boolean value. Then I recheck that my column in database is really boolean. It is (TRUE/FALSE). Then I set FalseValue "0" and TrueValue "1" and then get switched textboxes like in database is TRUE or FALSE. Then I have to give DataPropertyName to all other (text columns) in order to get data in grid. Then set other properties for each column. To be sincerely, I would much like to get all of this at runtime because of many similar existing code. But your solution work's. Thank's a lot.

Comment: Huh, again and again. I shouldn't add any columns columns! Just to change a properties of existing, autogenerated ones. As I wrote to "spajce", I can get checkboxes easily with unbinded DGV.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.
I had a DataSet that it was filling with this SQL:

```
"SELECT nombre, CASE WHEN fecha IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS baja"
```

Assignment

```
dtgEmpleado.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)

With dtgEmpleado
    .Columns(0).HeaderText = "Nombre"
    .Columns(0).DataPropertyName = "nombre"
    .Columns(0).Name = "nombre"
    .Columns(0).Width = 100
    .Columns(1).HeaderText = "Baja"
    .Columns(1).DataPropertyName = "baja"
    .Columns(1).Name = "baja"
    .Columns(1).Width = 70
End With
```

I wanted that the column "Baja" it was displaying as a "Checkbox".

I could do it with:

```
AutoGenerateColumns = False
```

But an easier way, changing the SQL sentence:

```
"SELECT nombre, CAST(CASE WHEN fecha IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS BIT) AS baja"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim cell As DataGridViewCell = New DataGridViewCheckBoxCell()

With DataGridView1
    With .Columns(1)
        .CellTemplate = cell
    End With
End With
```

**EDIT:**

This a suggestion, don't try to add columns at design-time in your `DataGridView` because you query itself it will generate a `DataGridViewCheckBoxCell`

```
GetData("SELECT myInt AS Id, myBool AS Bool, myString AS String " & _
        "FROM " & myFavTable & " " & _
        "WHERE (myInt > 100) ORDER BY myString")


Me.dataAdapter.Fill(myTable)
Me.bindingSource1.DataSource = myTable

DataGridView1.DataSource = bindingSource1;
```

Comment: Value provided for CellTemplate must be of type System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxCell or derive from it.

Comment: Thanks, but again with same results. Fact is that I don't ADD any column in my question. Just format it to avoid very slow autoformatting (AutoResizing). From that point of view my datagridview is binded and manually formated. If I completely remove my formatting still have 0/1 in those column. At some way I have to tell column(1) that there should be checkboxes. I achieve this with znbinded grid very easy by adding appropriate columns at runtime.